# How do I get 1Password Safari extension working in macOS

Tags: macos, safari-extension, 1password

I have macOS 1Password v8.7.1 and 1Password for Safari v2.3.5, but the extension won't show up in Safari Preferences. M1 MBP. Both 1P apps apps launch and the macOS app seems to work OK.

Works on my Intel iMac, but not on M1 MBP. Used to work but lately not.

Is there something to delete to make it reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command in the terminal

```
PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support:"$PATH"
lsregister -f /Applications/Safari.app
```